# Search website and return HTML elements to python to parse and get the values

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to pull the resulting County, State, and Zipcode from an address that is searched on this site https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php

I just cant get it to submit the form to get the address back in my results that are printed regardless of how I approach it

Current Code:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php'
payload = {
    'address': '123 cherokee drive cleveland ohio' #address to be searched on site
}

session = requests.session()
r = session.get(URL, data=payload)
print(r.text) #print results to parse
```